# Examination on a day of Ramadan

Tags: ramadan

I have the most important exam of my life which is unfortunately in the middle of ramadan. This examination is called JEE ADVANCE. In this examination, i need to concentrate for two shifts of 3 hour paper. So, i am confused about what would be better either fast or eat. Many of my friends suggesting not to keep fast on that day as you will not be able to concentrate properly without food.

Am i allowed to do that without disobeying allah swt ?

What could be done to fulfill that left out fast?

Comment: Fasting actually makes me more concentrated in my studies. In fact, intermittent fasting has overwhelming amount of backed up evidences proving it to be highly beneficial. Just google it. You'd be surprised.

Comment: I would do the same. I also wanted not to eat even i had misconception about fasting so that i could please my Creator. Don't get me wrong. Now that i know of this beautiful benefit. I would fast in coming days before ramadan inshallah!!

Comment: Just so you know, it is not allowed to fast few days before Ramadan begins unless it's a habitual fast. https://islamqa.info/en/answers/26850/prohibition-on-anticipating-ramadan-by-fasting-one-or-two-days-before-it-begins

Comment: Subhan allah. How knowledgeable you are! May allah increase you in knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something has been made obligatory upon you it is best you do what Allah says. Who would you rather listen to Allah or your friends? 
It is simple. Your surroundings and environment may impact you with all these individuals eating food but remember that your Creator is more important and His commands are more important than any test and all tests together whether they are life changing or not.
If it is best for you try to avoid contact with those who are eating or drinking as it may increase your hunger. I also have exams (GCSE's) during Ramadan and if I live till then In Sha Allah I ask Allah to help me with my fasts and exams and may Allah help you too.

Also, as the brothers said in the comments above fasting may be helpful try some fasts now and maybe get use to it.

Oh you who believe! Fasting is prescribed to you as it was prescribed to those before you, that you many learn piety and righteousness" (Q 2:183)

Comment: I would remember this my whole life. Now on Allah swt will be my first priority without thinking for a second over this worldly life inshallah!! .

Comment: You are welcome may Allah bless you brother.

Answer (score -2):

"Many of my friends suggesting not to keep fast on that day as you will not be able to concentrate properly without food." --> Is there any support for that statement?

Pythagoras had to fast [40 days to be admitted](http://9waysmysteryschool.tripod.com/sacredsoundtools/id13.html) to the school at Diospolis.
My biology teacher once told cognitive faculties are better when fasting.
A [study](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11325-017-1473-x) supports a positive correlation between fasting and increased alertness and improved cognitive function.

Comment: AFAIK Pythagoras was neither a  Muslim nor is this answer related to the topic of the site.